# javascript string as command line, why not eval()?

Tags: javascript, string, function, window, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

So I have read through MANY different methods on calling a function from a string, using `window[]();` and also `eval();`. I am wondering if for my situation (That is below) what method is exactly the right way to go ahead with, and if so, explain why. Also explain why `eval();` isn't exactly a good option, a lot of people say security, but why would security be an issue if you can get any browser plugin that enables you to change the script on that page? (example: firebug for firefox)

My current code:

```
funcOne(target).funcTwo(x, y, z);
```

How would call this using the recommended `window[]();` way? And why can't I use this?:

```
eval('funcOne(target).funcTwo(x, y, z)');
```

I don't want your annoyance of this question being asked many times, because I cannot currently think of a way to call a, as a call it, double function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are trying to build a Firebug-like command line? Please give a little more information. `eval` might be the right choice, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't see how you could get confused on the question enough to think I want to make a firebug-like command line, but What I meant was that I would like to call a function that is generated from information that is not known before runtime, so I save it and execute it, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript the syntax `a.b` can be replaced with `a["b"]`. So in your case you can use

```
window["funcOne"](target)["funcTwo"](x, y, z);
```

where of course it makes sense only if you are using variables instead of `"funcOne"` and `"funcTwo"`.

If everything is instead fixed but you simply want to delay execution you can use "thunking" with an anonymous closure with

```
x = function(){ return funcOne(target).funcTwo(x, y, z); };
```

and then you can evaluate with `x()` to get the desired result later.

The last example will work correctly even if the variables `target` and `x`, `y` and `z` are local to the enclosing scope because the thunking closure will "capture" them.

You should however pay attention to the fact that in Javascript the only way to create a new scope is to use a function (a block surrounded with `{` and `}` is NOT a scope like happens in C++ and other languages).

If you need to create several closures in a loop this can bite back and is a source of a quite common mistake...

```
for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++)
{
    var menu_item = document.createElement("div");
    menu_item.textContent = "Option " + i;
    menu_item.onclick = function () {
        // Warning this will NOT work. All divs will
        // alert using the same number!
        alert("Option " + i + " selected");
    }
    menu.appendChild(menu_item);
}
```

here I used a closure for the `onclick` event on the div, but this is not going to work because all those functions will use the very same `i` variable. Because in Javascript the only way to create a scope is using a function the solution is:

```
for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++)
{
    var menu_item = document.createElement("div");
    menu_item.textContent = "Option " + i;
    (function(i){
         menu_item.onclick = function () {
             alert("Option " + i + " selected");
         };
     })(i); // Pass current `i` as parameter
    menu.appendChild(menu_item);
}
```

This way the variable `i` inside the `onclick` handler will be different for each closure.

This pattern of creating a function just to call it immediately is often used in Javascript when you need to create many independent closures so it's better to know and understand it.

Comment: How would I achieve doing your second example with x() when all varaibles, target, x, y and z are scoped and I need to call it at any time while not within the same scope?

Comment: @pathurs: It would work because the thunk will "capture" the local variables. If however you need to create many thunks it's important to understand that what is captured is the **variable** and not the **value of the variable** and often the mistake is to create many closures unintentionally sharing the same variables. See the extended explanation...

Comment: Accepted and +1 due to detail of answer and multiple examples to give the best answer